# How safe is it to replicate from a Percona MySQL master to a MariaDB slave?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, percona

I have Percona MySQL running in production. We would like to Migrate to MariaDB server.

One of the solutions that came to my mind was using master-slave replication and then master swap technique.

Can anybody advice how safe it is to perform such operation? I worry about data corruption caused by incompatibilities in replication data formats.

Comment: What version of each?  What binlog format?  In general, a Slave (other Master) should not be a lower version.  So it becomes tricky to make sure anything to do with Replication is compatible enough between Percona and MariaDB.  Otherwise, it sounds like a good plan.